# C segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
int Search_in_File(char *fname,char *str){ 
    FILE *fp; 
    int line_num = 1; 
    int find_result = 0; 
    char temp[512]; 
    if((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL)
        return(-1);

    while(fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL){ 
        if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL){ 
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num); 
            printf("\n%s\n", temp); 
            find_result++;
        }
        line_num++;
    } 
        if(find_result == 0){ 
            printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
        } 
        if(fp)
            fclose(fp);
    return(0);
} 
void main(){
    char file_name[15]; 
    char *fname; 
    *fname=file_name[15]; 
    char *str; 
    char string_to_be_searched[15]; 
    *str=string_to_be_searched[15]; 
    int result, errno; 
    printf("Enter The File Name :"); 
    scanf("%s",fname); 
    printf("Enter The String To Be Searched :"); 
    scanf("%s",str); 
    result = Search_in_File(fname , str); 
    if(result==-1){
        perror("Error"); 
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errno);
        exit(1); 
    }
}
```

I wrote this little program to search string from a file but it shows segmentation fault(core dumped) in gcc Linux 
What is this error for ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Edit your question... you can use the return key to code

Comment: @Treycos can you precise please ?

Comment: Your code wasn't readable, i've edited

Comment: @Treycos is it readable now ?

Comment: there are only a couple of valid signatures for the `main()` function: All of them have a return type of `int`, never `void`

Comment: what are you expecting this line: `*fname=file_name[15];` to do?

Comment: in general, the handling of an error should be immediately after the thing that produced the error.  Suggest moving these lines: `    if(result==-1){
        perror("Error"); 
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errno);
        exit(1); ` to immediately after the call to `fopen()`   Note: the header file that contains the prototype for `exit()` also has the definition of `EXIT_FAILURE` which is a much clearer statement `exit( EXIT_FAILRUE)` than does `exit(1)`

Comment: when calling system functions, like `scanf()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with a `%s` format specifier, always include a max character modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid a buffer overflow (which would result in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: suggest elimination of the variable `fname`.  it just clutters the code.  suggest: ``if( 1 != scanf( "%14s", file_name ) ) { // handle error }

Comment: what are you expecting this line to do: `*str=string_to_be_searched[15];`?

Comment: suggest elimination of the variable `str`.  it just clutters the code.  suggest: `if( 1 != scanf( "%14s", string_to_be_searched ) ) { // handle error }

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.&  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case,, default) via a blank line.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 15, 512.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names and using those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: the function: `fgets()` includes the terminating newline character sequence (if available)  So must always remove such terminating newline, if present) before making comparisons.  Suggest using: `char *newline = NULL; if( NULL != ( newline = strstr( string, "\n" ) ) ) { *newline = '\0'; }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char *fname; 
*fname=file_name[15];
```

Think about what that code does. When you assign value to `*fname`, which memory does `fname` point to?

The answer is: `fname` is *uninitialized* pointer, which can point to any *random* location in memory. Most likely it contains `0`, so trying to dereference it results in immediate `SIGSEGV` (but this is not guaranteed).

You should also learn to use a debugger, which would point you straight at the problem.

Comment: actually, `fname` will contain the contents of the first byte past the end of the array `file_name[]` which could be anything in the range 0...255.

Answer (score -1):

This part of the code is causing the segmentation fault.

```
char file_name[15];
char *fname;
*fname=file_name[15];
char *str;
char string_to_be_searched[15];
*str= string_to_be_searched[15];
```

Your pointer needs to point to some address before you use it,

```
fname = file_name;
```

and

```
str= string_to_be_searched;
```

would take care of that.

So an appropriate code would be

```
char file_name[15];
char *fname;
fname=file_name;
char *str;
char string_to_be_searched[15];
str= string_to_be_searched;
```

Alternatively you could have also used malloc for assigning memory to your pointers

```
char *fname;
fname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
char *str;
str= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
```

Comment: in C, the returned type from the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*`.  such a type can be assigned to any other pointer.  casting the returned type just clutters the code making the code more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.